# Probability Problem Involving a Plot

Tags: probability

Suppose we select a random point inside the square defined by:  Ω={(,)∈2|0≤≤4,0≤≤4}
Consider the event ={(,)∈2||−|≤1} and suppose that B is the event formed by the exterior points to the triangle that’s limited by the lines: =2−;  =0 ; and =0.

Calculate the following probabilities: (∪), (∩), (−), and (−).

I made a plot which includes the square and triangle defined in the problem:

[image]

Then I calculated the area of each shape.

The area of the triangle is 2, and the area of the square is 16.
How can I use this information to calculate the probabilities?

Comment: Draw the lines $y=x+1$ and $y=x-1$ onto your graph.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the areas of the colored regions and divide by the total area ($16$) to get the probabilities.
[image: Areas corresponding to the events]